# How to create Unblockable Javascript Popup

Tags: javascript, popup

Nowdays browsers have popup blockers. But still I have seen some sites succeed to show popups. I also have to create a popup which can not be blocked by browser. Is it possible? if Yes then please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: Must ... not ... down-vote ... on principle.

Comment: On a more serious note, it seems that sites can open pop-ups unrestricted (in FF3.6) from flash (but also just from HTML?) *immediately after a user-initiated action* such as a click. I'm not exactly sure how it's done. Other browsers may behave differently.

Comment: I hate those. I'm not gonna tell you, I know how to, **but I hate those with passion** and it's better if you don't know.

Comment: Ptetty simple.. wenever u see such a site, look at the freakin source code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a popout with flash player. it bypasses browsers blocking criteria.

Comment: But then... flash is the next dinosaur.. #justsayin

Answer (score 4):

Without questioning the ethics of this question, browsers generally allow popups that are triggered by direct user actions - easpecialy click. It's the best chance your popup will show.

Otherwise 'ublockable' popups are thankfully not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I also have to create a popup which can not be blocked by browser. Is it possible?

No, you can't do this for all browsers.  Hopefully the reasons the better/newer browsers block this are quite obvious.  If you *need* a popup, add instructions on how to enable popups for your site for the browser they're using, don't try to bypass the security mechanisms that are there *for a reason*.

The **user** should make the choice for your site to have behavior different from the rest of the internet, not *you* forcing it on them.

Comment: what are the security issues with popups? Just wanted to know. So, is HDFC bank login too forcing its popup behaviour on the user? http://www.hdfcbank.com/personal/default.htm I checked that my firefox browser has popups disabled and this site is not added to exception but it still successfully displays popup and the entire netbanking functionality happens inside the popup window

Comment: @sandeepan - That site's popup isn't displaying in Chrome - what's what I meant by "for all browsers", the rules vary a bit between them.

Comment: please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232546/browser-window-popups-risks-and-special-powers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot; are you sure these are popups and not say for instance jQuery lightboxes?

Answer (score -1):

You can copy this code

```
<body onload="window.open('http://w3schools.com'),'popupwindow','width=520',;height=320'">
```

1. First of all you page run time Chrome automatically block, body onload popup,
   Click to right top - > press always allow this popup,
2. restart the page